# is it possible to read a csrf token from one site to allow access to content on another site

Tags: wordpress, cross-domain, session-state, session-cookies, csrf

Here is the scenario...

I have a site:

http://internet.com

and I set a token(cookie, something like that) from http://internet.com when a user has SUCCESSFULLY logged in.

I also have http://web.internet.com.

On http://web.internet.com I want to display data to users that have that token/cookie/etc available to them.

Here is the use-case

- user logs into http://internet.com (asp.net framework hosted on different server  -  this is our primary product that requires a subscription / username & login )
- user then has access to a section that is hidden from plublic view on http://web.internet.com (wordpress site hosted on goDadday -  this site contains a knowledge base that we do not want to make public unless they have done [XXXXX] )
- both sites are hosted independently of each other and do not share a common username and password
  ======

Another scenario is to set up wordpress to allow a specific section as a jsonp response. but only if the user is logged in at http://internet.com to allow the user to have access to the jsonp response located at http://web.internet.com

Any ideas from you beautiful people?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the level of security you require. You can log a user in to a Wordpress site without a password by using [wp_set_auth_cookie](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie), however if you are just validating that a user is logged into the ASP.NET site and then using JSONP to load a page that set's the auth cookie, it will work, however you definitely have some security gaps.

A better solution would be to set a domain level cookie for .internet.com with a token that can be read by any server in your domain. The Wordpress site could then check `is_user_logged_in()`, and if not take that cookie value and make a back end call to the ASP.NET site to verify its authenticity, and then call `wp_set_auth_cookie()`. A simple web service would likely be the best option. You would still need some level of mapping between usernames on the ASP.NET and Wordpress site however to know which user_ID to pass.